# Redrawing a ggplot graph with plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Out of curiosity I am trying to reconstruct a ggplot graph with plotly.

It is an example of a simple linear regression. The graph shows the observed data, the regression line and vertical lines showing the errors.

The ggplot looks like this: 
[image]

The reconstructed plotly graph looks like this:

[image]

1. Is there a way to push the vertical lines showing the errors to the back of the points?
2. Is there a better approach?

The data may be found here:
[Advertising.csv](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv)

This is the code used to make the plots:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(plotly)


    #### prepare data ####
    adv <- read.csv("Advertising.csv")

    fit_tv <- lm(sales ~ TV, data = adv)  

    adv_plot <- data.frame(adv, fit = fit_tv$fitted.values)

    #### ggplot ####
    p1 <- ggplot(adv_plot, aes(x = TV, y = sales)) + 
            geom_segment(aes(x = TV, xend = TV, y = sales, yend = fit), size = 0.5, color = "lightgrey") + 
            geom_point(color = "red") + 
            geom_point(aes(y = fit), color = "blue") 

    p1

    #### Plotly ####
    p2 <- plot_ly(adv_plot, x = ~TV, y = ~sales, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", marker = list(color = "red", size = 5)) %>% 
            add_trace(x = ~TV, y = ~fit, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", marker = list(color = "blue", size = 5))

    line <- list(
            type = "line",
            line = list(color = "lightgrey"),
            xref = "x",
            yref = "y"
    )

    lines <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(adv_plot$sales)) {
            line[["x0"]] <- adv_plot$TV[i]
            line[["x1"]] <- adv_plot$TV[i]
            line[["y0"]] <- adv_plot$sales[i]
            line[["y1"]] <- adv_plot$fit[i]
            lines <- c(lines, list(line))
    }
    p2 <- layout(p2, shapes = lines, showlegend = FALSE)
    p2
```

Comment: Have you tried `plotly::ggplotly(p1)`?

Comment: I tried it following your comment. It works fine. It is almost the same plot as with ggplot with added plotly interactivity. However I would like to do it completely with plotly to understand and learn how to use it and tweak it. Even if my motivation to not use ggplotly is not because of performance I bounced on this article this morning: [ggplotly vs plotly](https://www.r-bloggers.com/comparing-plotly-ggplotly-plot-generation-times/)

Comment: Managed to find the answer. If you are curios to see it I have posted the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end managed to find the answer myself. The order of the segments and traces keep the error lines in the background.

The data is here: [Advertising.csv](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv)

This is the code:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(plotly)
    adv <- read.csv("Advertising.csv")

    fit_tv <- lm(sales ~ TV, data = adv)  

    adv_plot <- data.frame(adv, fit = fit_tv$fitted.values)
    p <- plot_ly(adv_plot, x = ~TV) %>%
            add_segments(x = ~TV, y = ~fit, xend = ~TV, yend = ~sales, mode = 'line', line = list(color = "lightgrey")) %>% 
            add_trace(y = ~sales, name = 'trace 0', type = "scatter", mode = 'markers', marker = list(color = "red", size = 5)) %>%
            add_trace(y = ~fit, name = 'trace 1', type = "scatter", mode = 'markers', marker = list(color = "blue", size = 5)) %>% 
            layout(showlegend = FALSE)

    p
```